# Searching a better way of arranging dependencies and object files in nmake on windows

Tags: nmake

We are using nmake on windows to build our c applications.

Up to this time we had the following setting:

```
app1_build: module1.obj module2.obj module3.obj ...
cl app1.c module1.obj module2.obj module3.obj ...
```

Over the years these 2 lines grew more and more (maybe 40 or more object files)  and now it is difficult to understand.

Is there a way to arrange/structure it in another way (maybe vertically) so that it gets laid out in an more optimal way.

Thanks a lot in advance

Answer (score 1):

If you can, you should consider using GNU make instead of Microsoft NMAKE.  GNU make is the de facto standard make implementation, widely available on many platforms including Windows, and has many features to ease makefile authoring.  NMAKE is hamstrung in comparison.

If you must use NMAKE, the best you can do is to split the prerequisites across multiple dependency specifications.  For example, instead of

```
app1_build: module1.obj module2.obj module3.obj
```

You can use this:

```
app1_build: module1.obj
app1_build: module2.obj
app1_build: module3.obj
```

These two forms are identical to NMAKE, as it aggregates all of the prerequisites from all such specifications to determine the complete list of prerequisites for `app1_build`.

Then, you can use the special `$**` variable in commands, so you need not duplicate the list of prerequisites.  That is, instead of this:

```
cl app1.c module1.obj module2.obj module3.obj ...
```

You can use this:

```
cl app1.c $**
```

NMAKE will replace `$**` with the full list of all the prerequisities of the target being built.